# MySQL date_format () function vs SQL Like operator

Tags: mysql, sql

table: items_ordered

```
customerid  order_date  item    quantity    price
10330   30-Jun-1999 Pogo stick  1   28.00
10101   30-Jun-1999 Raft    1   58.00
10298   01-Jul-1999 Skateboard  1   33.00
10101   01-Jul-1999 Life Vest   4   125.00
10299   06-Jul-1999 Parachute   1   1250.00
10339   27-Jul-1999 Umbrella    1   4.50
```

I have the question like this 
"Select the average price of all of the items ordered that were purchased in the month of Dec?"

This is for MYSQL, and I've tried on SQL LIKE operator to solve it.

```
select avg ( price)
from items_ordered
where order_date like ('%Dec%')
```

However, I was thinking about another approach to this problem by using date_format:

```
select avg ( price)
from items_ordered
where date_format ( order_date, %M) = 'Dec'
```

My question is when we should you date_format function in SQL? and with this problem which one is solved faster?

Comment: Faster would be using the appropriate data type; `LIKE` and `DATE_FORMAT()` both eliminate the possibility of taking advantage of indexes, or using any built in date-based functionality.

Answer (score 5):

**Do not use `LIKE` for dates!**  `LIKE` is an operator for *strings* and dates are not *strings*.  MySQL has a bunch of built-in function for what you want to do.

If you want data from all Decembers, then use `month()`:

```
where month(order_date) = 12
```

If you want data from a single December, use date comparisons:

```
where order_date >= '2018-12-01' and order_date < '2019-01-01'
```

In particular, for a range of dates, direct comparisons can take advantage of an index.

Comment: Mentioning of using a probably existing index and its boost to query-performance when using range-comparison is the pro-tip to the second part of the question.